# How to find the rejected rows in informatica, while loading data from flatfile

Tags: oracle, etl, data-warehouse, informatica, flat-file

In this Scenario there are 18-20 flat-files which contains huge data, and only

one informatica session/workflow load the data in data-warehouse by processing one

file at a time. If there is an rejection of a row how do i know which row is

rejected and from which file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the rejected rows in the session log. Also all rejected records will be available in the bad file.

It is generally a good practice to capture all the known/ possible rejections by applying rules and writing them onto a file or table. Alternatively, you can enable loading of rejections directly into a table. There is an option in the session to do it.